# Cannot read property '_id' of undefined

Tags: nodejs, passport, handlebars

//este es mi index principal

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const app = express();
const passport = require('passport');
const session = require('express-session');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const exphbs =require('express-handlebars');
const SocketIo = require('socket.io');

//ARRANCADOR DE SERVIDOR
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
  defaultLayout: 'main',
  layoutsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'layouts'),
  partialsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'partials'),
  extname: '.hbs'
}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
require('./database');
require('./passport/local-auth');

//MIDDLEWARES
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

//VARIABLES GLOBALES
app.use( (req, res, next) => {
   app.locals.error_reg = req.flash('error_register');
   app.locals.init = req.flash('error_iniciar');
   app.locals.usr = req.user ;
   next();
});

//RUTAS
app.use('/', require('./routes/index.routes'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


//ESCUCHA DEL PUERTO
const server = app.listen(app.set('port'), ()=>{
    console.log(app.set('port'));
});
```

//Esta es mi autenticacion local

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const User = require('../models/user');

//SERIALIZAR
passport.serializeUser((user, done)=>{

    done(null, user.id);
});

//DESERIALIZAR
passport.deserializeUser( async (id, done)=>{

    const user = await User.findById(id);
    done(null, user);
});

//Registrar usuarios
passport.use('registrar-user', new LocalStrategy({

    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true

}, async (req, email, password, done)=>{
    var us = req.body.usuario;
    const eml = await User.findOne({email: email});
    const usr = await User.findOne({usuario: us});
    if (usr) {
        return done(null,
            false,
            req.flash('error_register', '*El usuario ingresado ya se encuentra en uso')
         );
        }else if (eml) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('error_register','*El Email ingresado se encuentra en uso.'));
        }else if (password != req.body.passwordd) {
             return done(null, false, req.flash('error_register', '*Sus contraseñas no coinciden'));
        }else if (password.length < 5) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('error_register', '*Su contraseña es demasiado corta'));
        }else{
            const newUser = new User();
            newUser.usuario = us;
            newUser.fc = req.body.fc;
            newUser.sexo = req.body.sexo;
            newUser.email = email;
            newUser.password =  await newUser.encryptPassword(password);
            await newUser.save();
            done(null, newUser);
        }
    }));

    //AUTENTICAR USUARIO

    passport.use('iniciar-user', new LocalStrategy({

        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true

    }, async (req, email, password, done)=>{
        const user = await User.findOne({email: email});
        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('error_iniciar', '*El usuario ingresado no existe.'));
        }else if (! await user.matchPassword(password)) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('error_iniciar','*La contraseña ingresada es incorrecta.'));
        }else {
            done(null, user);

        }
}));
```

//Este es mi modelo de usuario para poder guardar los datos de usuario en la base de datos de mongodb

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Schema} = mongoose;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');


const newUser = new Schema({
    usuario: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    fc: {type: String, required: true},
    sexo: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    registro: {type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

newUser.methods.encryptPassword = async (password)=>{
    return await bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10))
};

newUser.methods.matchPassword = async function(password){
    return await bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
}


module.exports = mongoose.model('usuarios', newUser);
```

//En el index.js hay una seccion llamada variables globales donde coloque las variables accesibles desde mi `.hbs`:

```
app.use( (req, res, next) => {
   app.locals.error_reg = req.flash('error_register');
   app.locals.init = req.flash('error_iniciar');
   app.locals.usr = req.user ;
   next();
});
```

//Cuando hay un inicio de sesion, la variable usr me retorna un objeto con los datos del usuario, hasta ahi todo va bien, pero cuando quiero acceder a esos valoresdes desde mi `.hbs`, no me permite, me devuelve `undefined`, si quiero visualizar el objeto me deja hacerlo, pero no me deja acceder a los valores, hace un mes busco soluciones y no puedo encontrar en ningun lado, por favor ayudenme

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cannot read property '\_id' of undefined](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/332370/cannot-read-property-id-of-undefined)

Comment: Por favor no dupliques preguntas

Comment: no tuve ninguna respuesta y estoy buscando ayuda

Comment: Duplicarlo no hará que las soluciones lleguen más rápido amigo, la ayuda puede ser inmediata o tardar o quizás no llegar, paciencia

Comment: Recibirías mas respuestas si formularas **mejores** preguntas. ¿ No has podido acotar mas el problema ? ¿ En que línea recibes el error ? ¿ Todo el código que has puesto es necesario ? Hay preguntas mucho mejor hechas a las que dedicar tiempo, en lugar de tener que mirar en todo tu código. Podrías comenzar por repasar lo que es un [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: Desconozco que es el `.hbs` que tienes definido. Leyendo se que es un motor de vistas. Al parecer te hace falta definir un paso mas para tener acceso a los `locales`. Lee [Exposing locals as template data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hbs#exposing-locals-as-template-data) para ver si te ayuda.